# changing body color with css

Tags: css, reactjs

How do I change the background color of my website because this doesn't work, please don't roast me too hard I hate css.

App.css

```
body {
    background-color: darkslategray;
}
```

App.js

```
import { Box, ChakraProvider, Image } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
        <Box>
          <Image
            src='https://data.whicdn.com/images/349387980/original.jpg'
            alt='Profile Image'
            boxSize={100}
            borderRadius='full'
            border='4px'
            borderColor='yellow'
          />
        </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should have `index.css` file somewhere

Comment: have you tried applying `!important`?

Comment: I have, it doesn't work aswell, Let me try !important

Comment: !important worked, thanks.

Comment: `!important` is an antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

Using important in styles is a bad practice and you should not use it as much as possible. In your case maybe some another style on body is over writing in your style so when you used the important applied your style